# Update a value if uid exists

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I would like to update a value to the MySQL database.

IF the user with the `uid` could not be found in the database, a new row should be added with the values of `uid` and `firstname` but if the `uid` exists in the database, only the value of the column `first_name` should be updated.

This is what I have so far:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$personal = new Personal();
$personal->setUid($uid);
$personal->setFirstName($value);

$em->persist($personal);
$em->flush();
```

This will simply add a new row but how can I update the value?

Comment: I suggest You to read this post https://medium.com/@galopintitouan/auto-increment-is-the-devil-using-uuids-in-symfony-and-doctrine-71763721b9a9

Comment: Just query the database for the person and then create a new person if it is not found.  The Doctrine ORM does not have any builtin update if exists, otherwise insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $search = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Personal::class)->findBy(array("uid" => $uid));
    if (count($search) == 0) {
        $personal = new Personal();
        $personal->setUid($uid);
    } else {
        $personal = $search[0];
    }
    $personal->setFirstName($value);

    $em->persist($personal);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: I get the error: Call to a member function setFirstName() on array

Comment: sorry @RezaSaadati i fix it ($personal = $search[0];)

Comment: Wow perfect, that works great. Thank you soo much!!